# Default Value For WPF Datagrid Column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in my WPF application.  I was wondering if there is a way to show default values for a column in the datagrid.  For example, I let the user have the ability to add new rows to the DataGrid.  Hence, at the bottom of the DataGrid, there is always a blank, empty row for the user to add data to.  I was hoping to have a default value for a column in this row.  Is there any way to achieve this functionality?  Thanks!

Comment: What is itemssource of your DataGrid?

Comment: The columns itemssource is an observablecollection<string>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say `ItemsSource` of your `DataGrid` is a Collection of `SomeClass` and you are displaying different `Properties` of `SomeClass` in DataGrid Columns. What you can do is in constructor of default `SomeClass` assign the `Properties` some default value. In this way you can have default column value in DataGrid.

**Edit**

As you said the `itemssource` of column is a string there is one way I can think of..

Make it collection of `SomeClass` which will only have a `string` property. In the default constructor of `SomeClass` assign this string a default value. That default value will appear in your data grid column

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do this with the help of `ValueConverters`. When `CanUserAddRows=Tru`e the `DataContext` of a row is bind to element of `ItemsSource` or to `{DataGrid.NewItemPlaceholder}` for the blank row.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Collection}" CanUserAddRows=True >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock
                    Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ShowSuitablePart}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And that's a code of `ShowSuitablePart` converter.

```
public class ShowSuitablePart : IValueConverter
    {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.ToString() == "{DataGrid.NewItemPlaceholder}")
            return "This is blank row, just click me to create a new one";
        else
            ((YourCollectionObject)value).SomeProperty;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

If you need `TwoWay` binding you'll have to use 2 elements in `DataTemplate`. One for the blank row, the second for regular rows with `TwoWay` binding. Set Visibility binding to hide the first element for regular rows and second element for blank row.

Remember if you determine Path to some property of you collection object it won't raise `ValueConverter` in blank row case.

Answer (score 0):

Create a CheckBox column on DataGrind and bind it to "myBoolColumn"

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Selected" Binding="{Binding myBoolColumn}" />

DataTable data = new DataTable();
data.Columns.Add("myBoolColumn", typeof(System.Boolean));
data.Columns["myBoolColumn"].DefaultValue = false;
```